# How many non-concentration buff spells are there?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells

Considering that you can't really cast multiple concentration-buff spells by yourself, I was curious how many non-concentration ones there were available. If someone could break each one down by which classes have access to it, that would be really great.
My idea of a non-concentration buff spell would be one that is in some way intended to either make whoever the spell is cast on stronger, harder to hit, faster, etc. And, I would also like to make it clear that I'm looking for spells with a duration of more than one round that are primarily cast on yourself/an ally. Something like Animate dead, though it gives you extra goons to possibly defend yourself with, I don't feel really counts, nor would a spell like guiding bolt, despite it having that whole "granting advantage on next attack" thing when it hits.

Comment: This question does have some broadness issues. You may want to help limit things a bit, by indicating if UA should be included, concisely defining what you consider a 'buff' spell, and indicating whether it's necessary to be able to target others or if just yourself is adequate.

Comment: I really don't see the question as being that broad since "buff" is a searchable term on D&D Beyond. It's a fairly generally understood term, isn't it?

Answer (score 7):

The spell listings on [D&D Beyond](https://www.dndbeyond.com/) are sortable and filterable for exactly the information you're asking about: [buffs without concentration](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells?filter-class=0&filter-search=&filter-tags=11&filter-verbal=&filter-somatic=&filter-material=&filter-concentration=2&filter-ritual=&filter-sub-class=).

At the time of this answer, it only includes the basic rules content, but that will change.

Comment: Cool site. I'm somewhat surprised that Mirror Image and Shield (in my experience, two of the more useful non-concentration buffs) are not on the list. (Shield only lasts one round, so wouldn't apply to the original poster's request: but I did notice that other 1 round buffs, like Guiding Bolt, are on the list provided).